# Is there a bug with the populist badge?

Tags: support, badges

The [Populist badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist) is defined as

> Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more
>   than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

At the time of this asking, and for several days previous, [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/is-there-faster-than-light-communication-in-the-star-wars-universe-other-than-h/6416#6416) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/is-there-faster-than-light-communication-in-the-star-wars-universe-other-than-h/6416#6416) has had 21 upvotes, while the accepted answer has had 10.

21 is exactly 1 more than 2x the accepted answers score, and the accepted answer has 10 upvotes.

I was looking forward to my first gold badge...did I misread something?

Comment: Did you get it yet?

Comment: Yes.  But I still feel foolish for my lack of reading comprehension.

Comment: @Jeff and you complain about my spelling ;P

Comment: I've been waiting for my populist badge too for quite a while. Damn accepted answer doesn't go beyond 10.

Comment: @apoorv020: And you get the badge, and you get the badge! Everyone gets the badge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the details in the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on the main meta site. It clarifies that “more than 10” and “more than 2x” are strict inequalities: the accepted answer needs to have a score of at least 11, and yours at least 23 (or more if the accepted answer has a higher score).

Answer (score 4):

> Answer outscored an accepted answer with a score of *more than* 10

The accepted answer still needs one more vote before you can earn your badge, by my calculation (it is still at 10).